# How to access to FastText classifier pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pipeline, word2vec, fasttext

As we know `Facebook`'s [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/) is a great open-source, free, lightweight library which can be used for text classification. But here a problem is the pipeline seem to be end-to end black-box. Yes, we can change the hyper-parameters from these [options](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/options.html) for setting training configuration. But I couldn't manage to find a way to access to the vector embedding it generates internally.

Actually I want to do some manipulation on the vector embedding - like introducing `tf-idf` weighting apart from these `word2vec` representations and another thing I want to to is oversampling using `SMOTE` which requires numerical representation. For these reasons I need to introduce my custom code in between the overall pipeline which seems to be inaccessible for me. How introduce custom steps in this pipeline?

Comment: Please clarify the reason for closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full source code is available:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText

So, you can make any changes or extensions you can imagine - if you're comfortable reading & modifying its C++ source code. Nothing is hidden or inaccessible.

Note that both FastText, and its `supervised` classification mode, are chiefly conventions for training a shallow neural-network. It may not be helpful to think of it as a "pipeline" like in the architecture of other classifier libraries - as none of the internal interfaces use that sort of language or modular layout.

Specifically, if you get the gist of word2vec training, FastText classifier mode really just replaces attempted-predictions of neighboring (in-context-window) vocabulary words, with attempted-predictions of known labels instead.

For the sake of understanding FastText's relationship to other techniques, and potential aspects for further extension, I think it's useful to also review:

- this skeptical blog post comparing FastText to the much-earlier 'vowpal wabbit' tool: ["Fast & easy baseline text categorization with vw"](https://nlpers.blogspot.com/2016/08/fast-easy-baseline-text-categorization.html)
- Facebook's far-less discussed extension of such vector-training for more generic categorical or numerical tasks, ["StarSpace"](https://github.com/facebookresearch/StarSpace)